# Ember set input value to JSON

Tags: json, binding, escaping, ember.js

I'd like to set the value attribute of an input the some JSON:

```
Ember.TextField.extend({
   valueBinding: Ember.Binding.transform(function(val){
      return JSON.stringify(val);
   })
});
```

If val="test" (a string) The element in the DOM is rendered like this:

```
<input id="ember881" class="ember-view ember-text-field" type="text" value="" test""="">
```

Is there a way to return some "SafeEscaped" version?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes. The following code should do the trick, though I'm sure there is a prettier solution somewhere:

```
return new Handlebars.SafeString(Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(JSON.stringify(val)).toString()).toString();
```

However (though I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with that code), I'd rewrite the view to read:

```
App.test = Ember.TextField.extend({
    valueBinding: 'test',
    val: {"cat":"meow"},
    test: function(){
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(JSON.stringify(this.val)).toString()).toString();
    }.property('val')
});
```

This should output:

```
<input type="text" value="{&quot;test&quot;:&quot;meow&quot;}" class="ember-view ember-text-field" id="ember239">
```

Note that I'm assuming you're using Handlebars.